# Remote service call through proxy

Tags: wcf, service, proxy, credentials

I'm trying to make a very simple service call from VS2012.
The service is on a domain outside a proxy and requires logon credentials.

I have set a refrence to the service in visuals studio. At that point i entered in the remote domian username and password and VS created all the proxy classes for me.

I then added this line to appconf file.

```
<system.net>
    <defaultProxy enabled="true" useDefaultCredentials="true">
    </defaultProxy>
</system.net>
```

Which i believe will allow me to get through our proxy using my own credentails

I then wronte this simple piece of code

```
    private void GetData()
    {
        OASIS.OasisServiceSoapClient o = new OASIS.OasisServiceSoapClient();

        o.ClientCredentials.UserName.UserName = @"OtherDimain\UserName";
        o.ClientCredentials.UserName.Password = "Password";
        var d = o.SelectOfficersAll();

    }
```

and of course it didn't work and i got all the errors that everyone has posted on.

So first question is 
do i need to add this

```
o.ClientCredentials.Windows.ClientCredential = System.Net.CredentialCache.DefaultNetworkCredentials;
```

because i did and still get that same stupid error 
"The HTTP request is unauthorized with client authentication scheme 'Anonymous'. The authentication header received from the server was 'Negotiate,NTLM'."

and inner exception

"{"The remote server returned an error: (401) Unauthorized."}"

so am i getting through the proxy ?
Am i using my own credentials ?
Am i passing the right paramaters in to the Service Model ?

Some examples show the username and password properties in the code above are to impersonate the current job.
But i read these on the MSDN page as being the credentials you want to use on the remote serve.  The Help topic is ambigious.  And if i don't enter them here then how ?

I'm trying to do something so simple , yet can't seem to get past this point.

Answer (score 0):

Ok thanks to my Colleague Sean.  It seems that depending on wether you are calling a web service or a WCF services determines what you need to do.

So as a web service this works

```
OASISWeb.OasisService s = new OASISWeb.OasisService();
s.Credentials =  new System.Net.NetworkCredential("Username", "Password", "Domain");
var d = s.SelectOfficersAll();
DataSet x = (DataSet)d;
```

if it's a WCF service then you need this

```
var service = new OasisTest2.ServiceReference1.OasisServiceSoapClient();
System.Net.WebRequest.DefaultWebProxy.Credentials =  system.Net.CredentialCache.DefaultNetworkCredentials;
service.ClientCredentials.Windows.ClientCredential = new System.Net.NetworkCredential("Username", "Password", "Domain");
var result = service.SelectOfficersAll();
```

It seems that WebRequest is a global object and you need to set the DefaultWebProxy.Credentails on it.

How you are suppose to know that ?  I never found any reference to it when i searched on how to connect to a WCF service on MSDN.  Must be a secret.  So keep it under your hat.